# How Convolutional layer work exaclty in RGB image processing?

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-processing, convolution

I'm studying convolutional layers and I'm pretty confused. Supposing that I give to my network (CNN) an RGB image, so an image with three channels. Since the image has 3 channels, then the kernels applied to my image will be 3 in each convolutional layer (I don't care exactly about the size of the kernels at this moment).

Therefore the convolutional operation at the first layer will be given by: the sum of the products between each channel of the image and the corresponding channel of the kernel (see figure below)

[image]

However, if it works in this way, the output of the first convolutional layer would be an image of two dimensions and not an RGB image with 3 channels, as I think, it should be.

Since it wasn't clear, I have found the following picture hoping that it could help me. However, it wasn't clear as well. Could anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if it works in this way, the output of the first
> convolutional layer would be an image of two dimensions and not an RGB
> image with 3 channels, as I think, it should be.

The output of the convolution between an image and a single kernel is a rank-2 tensor (has height and width, but only 1 channel).

A convolutional "filter" consists of one or more kernels, and the convolution between an image and a *filter* can be computed by taking all of the rank-2 outputs of convolving the image with each kernel, and stacking up to create a rank-3 tensor (has height, width, and "depth", or multiple channels).

---

Another way to describe things:

- An image is a CxHxW tensor (where C is usually 3)
- A kernel is a CxSxS tensor
- A filter is a KxCxSxS tensor
- Convolving an image with a kernel produces a H'xW' tensor (H',W' $\propto$ H,W).
- Convolving an image with a filter produces a KxH'xW' tensor